# Using bloginfo and divs inside a php file

Tags: php, theme-development, bloginfo

The following code is inside a .php file and works; however, I do not know how I can replace the TEXT with a **bloginfo('template_directory')** to an internal image file. I've search the forums but I cannot find a way to get this to work. Is there an easier way?

```
if ( $colors && in_array('green', $colors) ) {
    echo '<div class="asdsf">' . "TEXT" . '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're wanting an image tag in there too:

```
if ( $colors && in_array( 'green', $colors ) ) {
    echo '<div class="asdsf"><img src="';
    echo bloginfo('template_directory') . '/path/within/theme/to/img.png';
    echo '"></div>';
}
```

But it's better to use the newer `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` which will work whether or not you are using a child theme.

```
if ( $colors && in_array( 'green', $colors ) ) {
    echo '<div class="asdsf"><img src="';
    echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/path/within/theme/to/img.png';
    echo '"></div>';
}
```

Comment: Answer acceptance and votes are thanks enough! :-)  As long as it works, anyway!